# How to find and print a mysql pid file in c++

Tags: c++

I have gone through lots of websites about this topic, but I could not find any viable result relating to this.

If you can help me by giving some tips, then I will be greateful.

Comment: MySQL pid file you mean ?? check boost filesystem

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by querying MySQL to get the path to the PID file (SHOW VARIABLES LIKE pid_file) then:

```
FILE * f = fopen(path, "r");
fscanf(file, "%d", &pid);
fclose(file);
```